# Google Analytics Goals not working

Tags: google-analytics

I have set Goal in Google Analytic s two days before. Bu Hi there,

I have set Goal in Google Analytic s two days before. But i cannot any reports on my Google Analytic s Admin. Below of my settings.

URL look like below,

```
 /goto/2324/323
```

And i have set 'regular Expression' for this, the expression is *

> /goto/+[0-9]+/[0-9]+/

I think my goal setup is not working. What I did wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Regex needs to be modified in several ways, depending on what you are trying to match.

If you are trying to match "/goto/{one or more digits}/{one or more digits}", then your Regex would be:

```
\/goto\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+
```

(Note that forward slashes need to be escaped, and also that your placement of the "+" quantifier isn't being used properly. "+" means you want to match one or more of the previous character.)

If you want to match "/goto/{exactly 4 digits}/{exactly 3 digits}", then you can specify your Regex like this:

```
\/goto\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{3}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was use as you told. How can I test that working or not? When can i see the reports after changing the goal setup? Thanks Surya

Comment: You can test the regex and your strings at http://regex101.com or any other regex site. You should see results in real time reports or wait 24 hours for normal reporting.